# Which one is better to end the macro code with?

Tags: excel, vba

Screening through my code and I found I use two ways to end my code (after the = ). Just curious which is better way to use?

Example:

1) `ActiveSheet.Columns("A:BG").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = [AP2]`

2) `ActiveSheet.Columns("A:BG").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = Range("AP2").Value`

Any opinion?

Comment: Both are the same... However use second line which is mostly used and more popular than first one. First can make confusing for non experienced programmers.

Answer (score 2):

All of these produce the same result

```
[AP2]
[AP2].Value
[AP2].Value2
Range("AP2")
Range("AP2").Value
Range("AP2").Value2
Cells(2, 42)
Cells(2, 42).Value
Cells(2, 42).Value2
```

They are listed in ascending order of efficiency (ie `Cells` is fastest)

Which is 'best' is subjective, and up to you to decide for your situation.

BTW

`EntireColumn` is redundant, since `Columns("A:BG")` already specifies whole columns.

If compact is your aim, it can also be written as

```
[A:BG].ColumnWidth = [AP2]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand VBA better